# react-leaflet : trying to add onEachFeature props to GeoJSON but it wont work

Tags: reactjs, geojson, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet and GeoJSON to indicate an area on the map. I want to add onEachFeature in props for the GeoJSON so that when it clicks or hover on the map some info will pop(for example: `feature.geometry.type`). I will give an example below of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, LayersControl, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'

const { BaseLayer } = LayersControl;
const geoData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -142.734375,
              -6.315298538330033
            ],
            [
              158.203125,
              -6.315298538330033
            ],
            [
              158.203125,
              67.47492238478702
            ],
            [
              -142.734375,
              67.47492238478702
            ],
            [
              -142.734375,
              -6.315298538330033
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
export default class GeoExample extends React.Component {
  
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.geometry.type);
}

  style() {
    return ({
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: "blue",
      dashArray: "3",
      fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MapContainer center={[42.09618442380296, -71.5045166015625]} zoom={2} zoomControl={true}>
          <LayersControl position='topright'>
            <BaseLayer checked name='OpenStreetMap.Mapnik'>
              <TileLayer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
            </BaseLayer>
            <GeoJSON data={geoData} style={this.style} onEachFeature={this.onEachFeature}/>
          </LayersControl>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

you can try to compile it, the style prop is working as it should, the onEachFeature is my problem, because I am hovering and clicking over and nothing seems to pop.
Versions in package:

```
"react-leaflet": "^3.0.5",
"react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
```

Comment: works for me when clicking the polygon text polygon appears as a popup

Comment: [working fine for me too](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-haze-1nu6y)

Comment: when I hover over the the GeoJSON even my mosue wont change to show me it is clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of investigating why it is not working locally in my machine, the problem was I included wrong css for the leaflet and if I would guess something with the z-index was the problem, included the right css and everything works thanks for the support :)